# How to change app folder name in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, psr-4

I want to change main folder [app] to author name in laravel 5 how can I do that  can I do that without change anything in autoloader or composer ?

Comment: right-mouseclick on app directory => rename

Comment: can I do that without change anything in autoloader or composer ?

Comment: No. Change folder name, update `autoload.psr-4` attribute in your composer.json and run `composer dump`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have an entry on your composer.json file named "psr-4", inside change it to your new renamed directory.

```
 "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "your_new_directory/"
    }
  },
```

Then in command line run:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

Or

```
$ php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.3 your suggestion doesn't work as the path for `app` folder is hardcoded in `Application::path()` [see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L296), if you do this you might get the error: `Unable to detect application namespace.` To accomplish this you have to override the `Application` class in `bootstrap/app.php`.