# How to change the app path to api in Laravel 5 directory structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5 I'd like to change the default directory structure, so the path for `app` I want to move it to something like `api`, how can I accomplish this?

Example, instead of this structure:

```bash
.
├── app
├── bootstrap
├── config
├── database
├── public
├── resources
├── storage
├── tests
└── vendor
```

I want this:

```bash
.
├── api
├── bootstrap
├── config
├── database
├── public
├── resources
├── storage
├── tests
└── vendor
```

In my composer I've changed the namespace like so, as following this question: [How to change app folder name in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34180918/2845262):

```json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Api\\": "api/"
    }
},
```

But I'm getting the error:

```bash
[RuntimeException]                       
  Unable to detect application namespace.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a while I found a way to accomplish this, after look around for other answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34180918/2845262) I figured out that the `app` path is hardcoded in `Application::path()` [see the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L296)

Then I could make it work by overriding the `Application::path()` method:

```php
class Application extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
    /**
     * Overrides the path to the application "app" directory.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function path()
    {
        return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'api';
    }
}
```

Then update the `bootstrap/app.php`:

```php
// Overrides the PATH to use api instead of app
$app = new Api\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

Now I can have the following structure:

```bash
.
├── api
├── bootstrap
├── config
├── database
├── public
├── resources
├── storage
├── tests
└── vendor
```

A similar method was found in https://mattstauffer.co/blog/extending-laravels-application

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.7 you can now use `$app->setAppPath($path)`, like so:

```
$app->useAppPath(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../api'));
```

This can be called from `bootstrap/app.php`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @mitchdav! As of Laravel v5.7.23 this can be easily done by the `Application::useAppPath()` method.