# How to make a url like www.domain.com/app

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I am trying to make a URL like www.mydomain.com/app.
but now there is an issue because Laravel contains an app folder in it so it is not becoming possible to make a url like this.
When I tried to make it I received this[image: Access Forbidden]

Answer (score 1):

you can change the folder name of app in laravel 5.

please see this thread for more information

[How to Change App Folder Name in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180918/how-to-change-app-folder-name-in-laravel-5)

Comment: This is good but I am unable to change app folder name right now. any other solution?